# facebook.login() is not working in Corona SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, lua, coronasdk

I have went threw all the steps, creating a key hash for android for my game build in corona. I have create a Button for user login Facebook account. But don't have any error message and response when user touch the Button. Only have print output.

What am I missing? Please help.

- I have create the Key Hashes using OPENSSL
- Enter App ID from Facebook Developers
- Enter Key Hashes to Facebook Developers
- Enable "Single Sign On" and "Deep Linking"
- Enter Class Name "com.ansca.corona.CoronaActivity" on Facebook Developers
- include "android.permission.INTERNET"  in build.settings

```
local facebook = require ("facebook")
local fbAppID = "49911xxxxxx" 

local function onClick( event )
  if ( "ended" == event.phase ) then
    print( "Button was pressed and released" )
    facebook.login( fbAppID, facebookListener, { "publish_actions, email" } )
  end
end

-- Facebook Button
FacebookButton = widget.newButton
  {
    defaultFile = "images/fb.png" , 
    width = 240,
    height = 120,
    onEvent = onClick,
  } 
FacebookButton.x = display.contentWidth / 2
FacebookButton.y = display.contentHeight / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if you have fixed this problem but I too have been having problems with this. When you go to log in through Facebook and it gives you an error saying:

"invalid key hash code, it does not match xxxxxxxxxxxxx configure it in (your website here)" I copied the hash code and checked it over and over again...

Only to FINALLY realize that the lowercase "L" was actually an uppercase "i" o.0 it fixed it! Good luck to ya!
Also, here is a little code snippit that helped me a little

```
local function facebookListener(event)
    if (event.type == "session") then
        if (event.phase == "login") then
            sessionToken = event.token
            local response = event.response
            native.showAlert("My Response", response)
             --facebook.request("me", "GET", {fields = "email"})
        elseif (event.type == "request") then
            local response = event.response
            native.showAlert("My Response", response)
        end
    end
end
facebook.login( appId, facebookListener, {"publish_actions, email, public_profile"})
```